# Loading Data from Dropbox directly in Shiny App

Tags: r, rstudio, dropbox, shiny

This is a continuation of my previous question.
[Compress Data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573017/compress-data-in-r)

I thought to store data in dropbox and access it remotely.I used rdrop2 package of R to access dropbox and get the data from dropbox directly.

I know the connection to dropbox is working,I have been able to create folders (Single_Cell_RNAseq_data) and move files on dropbox from R Studio.

My app is running fine when I run the app locally in R Studio ,the data gets uploaded from the dropbox and can be visualized.

I saved the token locally.

```
token <- drop_auth()
saveRDS(token, "droptoken.rds")
```

### in the global.r Script

```
token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")
geneExpressionMatrix_yf1 <-    drop_read_csv("Single_Cell_RNAseq_data/geneExpressionMatrix_yf1.csv",dtoken=token)
```

But while deploying on shinyapps.io, its throwing me this error.

An error has occurred
Unable to connect to worker after 60.00 seconds; startup took too long.

I found another post and tried to read the tokens and the files in server.r script, but still not able to read the files in the App.
[Loading image file from Dropbox into R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197751/loading-image-file-from-dropbox-into-r-shiny-app)

Here is the **beginning** of my server.r script

```
token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")

drop_acc(dtoken = token)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



 observeEvent(input$text,{







output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

  geneExpressionMatrix_yf1 <- drop_read_csv("Single_Cell_RNAseq_data/geneExpressionMatrix_yf1.csv",dtoken=token)
  tsneCoordinates_yf1 <- drop_read_csv("Single_Cell_RNAseq_data/tsneCoordinates_yf1.csv",dtoken=token)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem (and I would have left a comment rather than an answer but I don't have enough points), but when I've done this I have just saved the droptoken.rds file and the .httr-oauth file in the app folder and don't call them explicitly in the server.R file. I simply just use the `drop_read_csv` command without any other arguments

```
mydata<-drop_read_csv('MyData.csv')
```

Comment: ClaytonJY confirms 
 your approach. Future readers [see his preferred method here](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2/issues/61#issuecomment-423329873) of setting authenticate with that token like drop_auth(**rdstoken** = "tokenfile.rds") in global.R or at the top of server.R, then call other drop_*() functions normally (without using the dtoken arg). Note see it is rdstoken not token